# Sampling from a gamma distribution and computing its likelihood

Tags: python, sampling, model-selection, likelihood, gamma-distribution

I would like to conduct a model comparison analysis of a process that is modelled with a gamma distribution. To illustrate, let's consider the example of sampling the time of incidents in a factory. The data available to me consists of the times $t_k$ at which the incident $k$ occurs.

To generate K samples, what I do is generate different time intervals using the gamma density function. Then, I perform a cumulative sum to obtain the times at which each incident occurred. Subsequently, I use the gamma distribution function to compute the log-likelihood.

The problem that I'm founding is that  the log-likelihood that the last incident happen, if I consider that it happen after the first one, is higher than considering all the incidents. Am I doing something wrong?

Here is the Python code I am currently using:

````
import numpy as np

from scipy.stats import gamma


beta = 2.14
shape = 1.0
K = 100

T = np.random.gamma(shape = shape, scale = beta, size = K).cumsum()
s = 0
for i in range(len(T)-1):
    s += np.log(gamma.pdf(T[i+1],shape,T[i],beta))
print("complete likelihood",s,"Just the last and final likelihood", np.log(gamma.pdf(T[-1],1,T[0],beta)))

```
````

Comment: What is `r` in your last line? It is normal that the likelihood of a single event is higher than that of several events (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunction_fallacy). Besides, the gamma parameters in your last and second to last lines are not the same.

Comment: Sorry, I did a mistake in my example, but in any case I'm confused. It's true that can it be a problem of conjunction fallacy, but the log-likelihood it's supposed to be additive, so as more data I have, more likely will be my model. I have to think more. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: No, the more data you have, the more accurate your estimate of the parameters will be, but you cannot conclude anything regarding their likelihood.

Comment: Of course that by adding more data I will have better accuracy of the prameters, but what I want is to ONLY compute the likelihood using the parameters that generates my model, no estimating them. The problem that I observe is that the probability of having an incident in a huge time interval is higher than the probability of having different incidents in small time intervals. If I want to predict unobsreved incidents, it would be impossible.